# Converting PS1 (calling theFileSystemWatcher class) to a Service using NSSM

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher, winscp, nssm

I created a powershell script that transfers any created file (using WinSCP) to a remote server, then moves the file to another local folder. The script works perfectly; however, it needs to start on server startup. Creating a service is the best option. I can convert the PS1 file to a service using NSSM; however, when I try to start it, the status changes to PAUSE and the following error is returned: Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Doc Manager (Doc Manager)'. It must be an issue with the script as I have used this method for many scripts in the past.

```
using namespace System.IO

# Create watcher
$fsw = [FileSystemWatcher]::new("C:\PowerShell\DocSource")
$fsw.NotifyFilter =
[NotifyFilters]::LastAccess,
[NotifyFilters]::LastWrite,
[NotifyFilters]::FileName,
[NotifyFilters]::DirectoryName

# Define handler methods
$handler_OnChanged =
{
    param([object] $source, [FileSystemEventArgs] $e)
        
        # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
        Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

        # Set up session options
        $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
            Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
            HostName = "SOMEIPADDRESS"
            UserName = "sftpuser"
            Password = "SOMEPASSWORD"
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 SOMEKEY"
            Timeout = new-timespan -minutes 1
        }

        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

        try
        {
            # Connect
            $session.DebugLogPath = "C:\PowerShell\Scripts\docs.log"
            $session.Open($sessionOptions)

            $source = "C:\PowerShell\DocSource\*"
            $destination = "C:\PowerShell\DocDestination\"   
            
            # Set Options
            $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
            $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary  

            # Transfer cp files
            $session.PutFiles($source, "/files/*", $False, $transferOptions).Check()

            # Move files from source to destination
            Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | ForEach-Object {   
                $nextName = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.name
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $nextName -Force
            } 
            
        }
        finally
        {
            $session.Dispose()
        }

}

# Wire of event handlers
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Created -Action $handler_OnChanged
```

Comment: Did you consider scheduling the script to run on a system start with Task Scheduler instead?

Comment: You can't run a ps script through the scheduler. We've tried a similar method using a batch file to call the ps script; however, the bat is unable to run the script. We can't figure out why.

Comment: *"You can't run a ps script through the scheduler"* – Of course that you CAN. If you have problems with starting the script both in scheduler and even in nvvm, why are you asking about the nvvm, rather than about the scheduler? Scheduler is designed for this.